# js radiobutton checked не работает

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно чтобы при выборе определенной radiobutton и вызове функции goGoGo() менялся цвет(класс) соответствующего блока (div). Но при выполнении функции переменные radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4 все равно имеют значение null. Как это исправить?

```js
// create wrapper
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
var parentWrapper = document.querySelector('body');
parentWrapper.insertBefore(wrapper, parentWrapper.children[0]);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  //create 4 divs
  window['box' + i] = document.createElement('div');
  window['box' + i].classList.add('box' + i);
  window['parentBox' + i] = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  window['parentBox' + i].insertBefore(window['box' + i], window['parentBox' + i].children[i]);
  window['box' + i].classList.add('green');
  window['box' + i].setAttribute('id', 'boxId' + i);

  //create 4 inputs
  window['input' + i] = document.createElement('input');
  window['input' + i].classList.add('input' + i);
  window['parentInput' + i] = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  window['parentInput' + i].insertBefore(window['input' + i], window['parentInput' + i].children[i + 4]);
  window['input' + i].setAttribute('type', 'radio');
  window['input' + i].setAttribute('id', 'radio' + i);
  window['input' + i].setAttribute('name', 'family');
};

// create button
var buttonGo = document.createElement('input');
buttonGo.classList.add('buttonGo');
buttonGo.setAttribute('type', 'button');
buttonGo.setAttribute('value', 'GO!');
buttonGo.setAttribute('onclick', 'goGoGo()');
var parentbuttonGo = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
parentbuttonGo.insertBefore(buttonGo, parentbuttonGo.children[9]);

function goGoGo() {
  var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1').checked;
  var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2').checked;
  var radio3 = document.getElementById('radio3').checked;
  var radio4 = document.getElementById('radio4').checked;

  var divBox1 = document.getElementById('boxId0');
  var divBox2 = document.getElementById('boxId1');
  var divBox3 = document.getElementById('boxId2');
  var divBox4 = document.getElementById('boxId3');

  if (radio1) {
    divBox1.classList.remove('green');
    divBox1.classList.add('red');
  }
  if (radio2) {
    divBox2.classList.remove('green');
    divBox2.classList.add('red');
  }
  if (radio3) {
    divBox3.classList.remove('green');
    divBox3.classList.add('red');
  }
  if (radio4) {
    divBox4.classList.remove('green');
    divBox4.classList.add('red');
  };
};
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: а где проверяется значение внутри функции? стоит посмотреть разметку которую вы генерируете, заметьте, что счетчик идет от 0 до 3, а вы берете элементы от 1 до 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка (опечатка?) в том, что в цикле генерируются элемент с ид от 0 до 3, а в обработчике пытаются взяться от 1 до 4, соответственно для последнего элемента, так как его нет, будет вернут `null`
Достаточно при присваивании id увеличивать счетчик на единицу

```
window['input' + i].setAttribute('id', 'radio' + (i+1));
```

Пример:

```js
// create wrapper
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
var parentWrapper = document.querySelector('body');
parentWrapper.insertBefore(wrapper, parentWrapper.children[0]);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  //create 4 divs
  window['box' + i] = document.createElement('div');
  window['box' + i].classList.add('box' + i);
  window['parentBox' + i] = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  window['parentBox' + i].insertBefore(window['box' + i], window['parentBox' + i].children[i]);
  window['box' + i].classList.add('green');
  window['box' + i].setAttribute('id', 'boxId' + i);

  //create 4 inputs
  window['input' + i] = document.createElement('input');
  window['input' + i].classList.add('input' + i);
  window['parentInput' + i] = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  window['parentInput' + i].insertBefore(window['input' + i], window['parentInput' + i].children[i + 4]);
  window['input' + i].setAttribute('type', 'radio');
  window['input' + i].setAttribute('id', 'radio' + (i+1));
  window['input' + i].setAttribute('name', 'family');
};

// create button
var buttonGo = document.createElement('input');
buttonGo.classList.add('buttonGo');
buttonGo.setAttribute('type', 'button');
buttonGo.setAttribute('value', 'GO!');
buttonGo.setAttribute('onclick', 'goGoGo()');
var parentbuttonGo = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
parentbuttonGo.insertBefore(buttonGo, parentbuttonGo.children[9]);

function goGoGo() {
  var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1').checked;
  var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2').checked;
  var radio3 = document.getElementById('radio3').checked;
  var radio4 = document.getElementById('radio4').checked;

  var divBox1 = document.getElementById('boxId0');
  var divBox2 = document.getElementById('boxId1');
  var divBox3 = document.getElementById('boxId2');
  var divBox4 = document.getElementById('boxId3');

  if (radio1) {
    divBox1.classList.remove('green');
    divBox1.classList.add('red');
  }
  if (radio2) {
    divBox2.classList.remove('green');
    divBox2.classList.add('red');
  }
  if (radio3) {
    divBox3.classList.remove('green');
    divBox3.classList.add('red');
  }
  if (radio4) {
    divBox4.classList.remove('green');
    divBox4.classList.add('red');
  };
};
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```